# Place elements in a single row including a table with 100% width

Tags: html, css

I've got 3 elements in a div with an overflow. First two are divs, third is a table. I need to place them in a single row.

My table's width is determined by cell width. Setting a table width would make this easy, but I can't do that because cell number varies. I want it to overflow a parent div and make it scrollable and not shrink based on parent width. This was achieved by setting a table's width to 100% and setting it table-layout to fixed. But because it has width set to 100%, it puts it in a second row.

I can't set position absolute on table because it's contained within a moveable div. I need it to be relative to parent div. I've found it's doable by setting a negative margin-top on table, but I would prefer to not have this hardcoded in case height of my first two elements changes.

Here is a JSFiddle of my situation: https://jsfiddle.net/9mvjftag/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-row">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="second-row">
    test
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container > * {
  float: left;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
}
```

How do I achieve this? Changing table's css is fine as well if there's another way to achieve my current situation (it's width determined by cell width, overflowing the parent div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [article](https://medium.com/flexbox-and-grids/how-to-create-horizontally-scrollable-sections-with-flexbox-60d860f539b2) that may help you it involves using Flexbox.

so in your case, this may work

HTML

```
<ul class='row'>
  <li class='item'></li>
  <li class='item'></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.row{
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  display:  flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.row::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

 .item{
   background-color: #e74c3c;
   min-width: 200px;
   margin: 5px;
 }
```

all the class names or HTML selectors can be interchangeable and I just used %ul and %li and examples

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. You may want to edit your answer though, answers with links only are not encouraged as they can change or die.